# unicode & special characters in delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

our delphi win32 app uses special characters like micro and copyright.  we mostly use the arial.  before delphi 2009, we had to provide a way to prevent the micro character from displaying since for some (many/most?) parts of the world, it was not displayed correctly.  we'd replace micro with u, copyright with (C)...

now that we're in delphi 2009, can we leave out this option and display the micro & copyright symbols without needing to do this translation.

it would seem to me that this should work everywhere now without this lame replacement scheme now that our app is in unicode.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as you're using Unicode strings and not ANSI strings, you can put in whatever extended characters you'd like, and they'll show up properly as long as the font you're displaying in supports them.

Answer (score -1):

I'd test it in a few differnt languages first though.  Unicode is not always as Universal as we sometimes believe.